# Replace text from span if div text contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Replace from `<span class="redbadge">` the text **No** with Yes **if** div contains the text `I am now visible`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="visibleonsearch">
<span class="redbadge">No</span>
I am now visible.
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
​   ​$(".visibleonsearch").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("No", "Yes"); 
});​​​​​ 
</script>
```

I am not familiar with jQuery to add the condition **if**.

Comment: Should the `span` be left in the HTML or removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `:contains` selector like the following way:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if($(".visibleonsearch:contains(I am now visible)").length){
    var span = $('.visibleonsearch').find('.redbadge'); 
    span.text(span.text().replace("No", "Yes"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="visibleonsearch">
  <span class="redbadge">No</span>
  I am now visible.
</div>
```

Comment: This removes the `span` though. The OP doesn't state if that's a requirement

Comment: Your code works correct in a JSFiddle, but on a WordPress website do not works and no error in console. My text "I am now visible" appear after a while, when user take an action (click a link) > other jQuery. Can be this the reason? The code must be adapted if the text "I am now visible" appears after a while? (user action).
My code put in header of WordPress page is: https://ibb.co/s9Dm58L

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to change the text of the `span` while leaving the `span` itself in the DOM then you can use `:contains` to find the relevant `.redbadge` element, like this:

```js
$('.visibleonsearch:contains("I am now visible") .redbadge').text('Yes');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="visibleonsearch">
  <span class="redbadge">No</span> I am now visible.
</div>
```

Comment: The same problem, my text "I am now visible" appears after a while, when user take an action (click a link), so do not change the span value from No to Yes only if both of them are present on the same time. Solution?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you add an example to the question. It sounds like the `.visibleonsearch` elements are being added to the DOM after the page loads as well, in which case you need to execute the above cases then too.

Comment: When page load div and span are present. User have a link via jQuery >  "Made my listing visible". When user click this link an update in database are performed and appear the text: "I am now visible", now the value of my span should change to Yes.

Comment: In which case you need to run the above logic after that change occurs. How you do that entirely depends on what is making that text appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".visibleonsearch:contains(I am now visible.)").find(".redbadge").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("No", "Yes"); 
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="visibleonsearch">
<span class="redbadge">No</span>
I am now visible.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```